# emojii sofkeyboard without drawable

Tags: android, unicode, android-softkeyboard, emoji, custom-keyboard

I implemented the [ankushsachdeva_project](https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon) to display emojii in my SoftKeyboard.
Is there a way to modify this library to display the unicode character in the popup (edittext) instead of the corresponding drawable? 
I want to do this so that every device can display the emojii according to its own style and font